# Change TextView String Resource in multiple activities

Tags: android

I have a bunch of TextViews within different activities in my app that show some string.

I wanted to add an option somewhere, where if you check it (or press it, whatever) those textviews will use some other string.

I though I could do it with having a second res value strings, and the app will switch between the two. But I see those are for localizing and do not use any user input.

Comment: Should've added that I want option to affect all activities.

Comment: Is using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) an option? User input will load the so called *second* string resource and save its value to SharedPreferences as well as using it for the TextView of the current activity. All the other activities can be updated by reading what was written to SharedPreferences as soon as OnResume gets triggered.

Comment: My suggestion is you need to create one flag in session and check if the flag is 1 apply your alternative strings in your required activity otherwise change another format whatever you want.So you have to check that flag every time in your app and change it.@MazzingerPawa

Comment: @DavidMichaelHuber
SharedPreferences was enough and quite convenient since I did want the app to check if there was a string chosen at the start. Thanks.

Comment: @MazzingerPawa Great! I added my comment as an answer which is a little bit more specific for others having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement seems like you need DataBinding. You can create a Model call lets say `StringManager`

```
public class StringManager {
    private final String str;
    private final String str2;
    private final String str3;
    public StringManager(String str1,String str2, String str3){
        //Initialize all class variables here
    }
    //Create getter methods for all
}
```

In your `main_activity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <data>
       <variable name="stringManager " type="com.example.StringManager "/>
   </data>
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@{stringManager.str1}"/>
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@{stringManager.str2}"/>
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@{stringManager.str3}"/>
       <Button
           android:id="@+id/btnClickMe"
           android:text="Click me"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:onClick="clicked"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

In your `MainActivity.java`

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
        private MainActivityBinding binding;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
           binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_activity);
           StringManager stringManager = new StringManager("strA", "StrB", "StrC");
           binding.setStringManager(stringManager);
        }

        public void clicked(View v){
           StringManager stringManager = new StringManager("strD", "StrE", "StrF");
           binding.setStringManager(stringManager);
        }
    }
```

You can find the official tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Due to there is no specific piece of code in the answer I will just sketch out my solution as pseudo code.

This solution is based on the `onResume` callback which is getting called as soon as an activity is getting active and the [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) class. As well it is important to know that only one activity will be active at once.

1. Initialize a variable as `SharedPreference` with the default string resource
2. User input changes that exact variable which is stored as 
   `SharedPreference` instead of the `TextView`'s text itself. The nature of a `SharedPreference` will make it so that every button in every activity references the same variable. The second string resource can be used as source here.
3. The `TextView`'s text is getting updated by using the `SharedReference` variable only.
4. - In case of a new activity becoming active `onCreate` can be used to update the `TextView`'s text by using the `SharedReference` variable.
   - In case of an other already initialized activity becoming active `onResume` can be used to update the `TextView`'s text by using the `SharedPreference` variable